# Plotting an array of events with respective colours

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I'm pretty new to matplotlib and I'm trying to plot an array for time-series use, but I don't use a date, only the index for order. I have another array with a colour code for every entry in the previous array.

I'm trying to plot them similar to [this](https://bbengfort.github.io/assets/images/2016-01-28-timeline.svg) but only in one line.

My data looks like:

```
array = ['event0', 'event1', 'event2', 'event0', 'event6', ..]
colours = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'r', 'y', ..]
```

Comment: The data you show us and your comment under @shivammittal99 answer is troubling me, what are you plotting exactly ? Timestamps ? A list of string ? Something else ?

Comment: How do you imagine to have duplicates to be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# input data
array = ['event0', 'event1', 'event2', 'event0', 'event6']
colours = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'r', 'y']

# for easier plotting, convert your data into numerical data:
```

#### method 1:

#### events of same type get same y-coordinate

```
array_numbers = [float(a.split('event')[1]) for a in array]
```

#### method 2:

#### all events get the same y-coordinate:

```
array_numbers = [1 for a in array]
```

#### plotting:

```
# create figure, and subplots
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

# plot newly generated numbers against their index, using the colours specified
ax.scatter(range(len(array_numbers)), array_numbers, c=colours)

# create ticklabels:
y_tick_labels = ['sensor-{}'.format(a) for a in range(7)]

# set positions of ticks, and add names
ax.set_yticks(range(7))
ax.set_yticklabels(y_tick_labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.scatter(x, y, c=colours)`

Comment: I've tried this but it does not work for duplicates (ex. event0 showing up at 2 different times). It only plots the first occurence for each event